# how to apply index&match function on my excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

[image]

i have 10,000rows of data like this. I want to add a new column titled AGE at D using the data on the right. is there a VBA that can do this?

I tried using the following steps but it keeps crashing due to large file

1. apply highlight duplicate condition on both NAME collumns,
   2.sort by cell color

Comment: 10,000 rows isn't a large file for Excel. How large is the file? Is it corrupt? Have you tried repairing it?

Comment: Hi @JENN,, I think that U have not done enough research,, otherwise 10,000 rows are not a  big issue,, possibly U are working with quite OLDER CPU,,, also you have not shared the VBA code, applied and [please  check this](https://superuser.com/help/asking) or [this one](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask)☺

Answer (score 1):

Your true question seems to be: How to match names and pick out the age from the table on the right and show it in an added column in the left table.

The answer, for your example data, adjust for the real data:
Type `=VLOOKUP(A3,$G$3:$H$6,2,0)` in D3, press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>
Select cell D3 again and copy it down into D4:D6.

You may add `IFERROR(...,"any text")` so that you get `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A3,$G$3:$H$6,2,0),"any text")` - which will show "any text" when a name can't be found.

Note that the last `0` in vlookup can be changed to a `1` if you sort the names in the age table. I'm not entirely sure what the results may be if you have a longer non-sorted age table (compared to the example).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `INDEX` and `MATCH` to get the results. On D3, insert the formula below and drag it down.

```
=IFNA(INDEX(H3:H6,MATCH(A3,G3:G6,0)),"")
```

If you have Office 365 then you can also use `XLOOKUP` as shown on this formula:

```
=XLOOKUP(A3,G3:G6,H3:H6,"",0)
```

Both formulae check if the value of `A3` is found in `G3:G6` range. If found, the age is shown. If not an empty text is shown.

***Using INDEX and MATCH***

[image: IMG:]

***Using XLOOKUP***

[image: IMG:]

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A3=$G$3:$G$6)*($H$3:$H$6))
```

[image]